# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded ONLY on Production

Tags: angular, angular-cli, auth0, firebase-hosting, zonejs

**Update Aug. 28: The exact same package configuration below but with `zone.js 0.8.16` instead produces no errors. Any idea why?**

**Edit: I've been trying to find out just where the problem is coming from. If this is an endless loop, where exactly does it occur, but I'm failing to decipher the code in polyfills or vendor.**

I'm deploying my Angular app using Firebase Hosting. When compiling and testing using localhost, everything works fine. But when I deploy on Firebase Hosting, my live site is never able to bypass logging in using Auth0, giving me the same error below endlessly in the console. How can I find out what's causing the error exactly?

```js
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
(anonymous) @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
o.(anonymous function) @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
_makeRequest @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
_sendProcessedPayload @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
_send @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
_processException @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
_handleStackInfo @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
captureException @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
L @ polyfills.70fc3f963669a0ddfcd2.bundle.js:1
r @ vendor.bd83d2a24392414468c4.bundle.js:1
```

Here's the list of packages my in project:

`├── @agm/core@1.0.0-beta.1
├── @angular/cli@1.3.2
├── @angular/common@4.3.6
├── @angular/compiler@4.3.6
├── @angular/compiler-cli@4.3.6
├── @angular/core@4.3.6
├── @angular/forms@4.3.6
├── @angular/http@4.3.6
├── @angular/platform-browser@4.3.6
├── @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@4.3.6
├── @angular/router@4.3.6
├── @ngx-translate/core@7.2.0
├── @ngx-translate/http-loader@1.0.2
├── @types/jasmine@2.5.54
├── @types/node@8.0.25
├── angular2-jwt@0.2.3
├── apollo-angular@0.13.0
├── apollo-client@1.9.1
├── auth0-js@8.9.3
├── bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6
├── codelyzer@3.1.2
├── core-js@2.5.0
├── graphql-tag@2.4.2
├── jasmine-core@2.8.0
├── jasmine-spec-reporter@4.2.1
├── jquery@3.2.1
├── karma@1.7.0
├── karma-chrome-launcher@2.2.0
├── karma-cli@1.0.1
├── karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter@1.3.0
├── karma-jasmine@1.1.0
├── karma-jasmine-html-reporter@0.2.2
├── mq-scss@1.2.4
├── mydatepicker@2.0.27
├── ngx-stripe@0.1.0
├── ngx-swiper-wrapper@4.6.0
├── protractor@5.1.2
├── raven-js@3.17.0
├── replace-in-file@2.6.3
├── rxjs@5.4.3
├── sass-mq@3.3.2
├── ts-node@3.3.0
├── tslint@5.7.0
├── typescript@2.3.4
└── zone.js@0.8.17`

If I run `ng serve` everything works well and I can login. If I run `ng build --prod` then `firebase serve` (trying to simulate the production environment) I get the error above when I try to login. Logging in = simply calling Auth0's `webAuth` client library, which never ends up calling back my function.

Comment: If that were the case, why does it occur only on the production (live) server and never on localhost?

Comment: Please, provide ways for reproducing your issue (e.g. git repository or at least, what packages - and versions - are you using). You're not even mentioning what angular/angular-cli version you're using...

Comment: I'm very sorry. I'll update the question now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error has been reported [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7502) and [here](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/886) and will probably be fixed by the next release of `zone.js`